# Modify font size using className in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to modify font size for the following component using `className="form_input"` but it does not change the font size:

```
class Search extends Component {
  render() {
    const { filterVal, filterUpdate } = this.props;
    return (
      <form>
        <br />
        <input
         className="form_input"
          type="text"
          ref="filterInput"
          placeholder="Type to filter.."
          value={filterVal}
          onChange={() => {
            filterUpdate(this.refs.filterInput.value);
          }}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

I am importing as follows:

```
import "./index.css";
```

This is the index.css file:

```
form_input {
   font-family: "Roboto", "Oxygen", "Ubuntu", "Cantarell";
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-size: 40px;
}

body {
  margin: 20;
  font-family: "Roboto", "Oxygen", "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans",
    "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New",
    monospace;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using class so change your `form_input` to `.form_input` because it's about css selectors you can practice more here https://flukeout.github.io/